# Coppersmith attack on NTRU and non-commutativity

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography, lattice-crypto, ntru, commutative-encryption, non-commutative-cryptography

In [this paper](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F3-540-69053-0_5.pdf), Coppersmith and Shamir used lattice reduction to attack NTRU. At the very end of the paper, they note that developing non-commutative variants of NTRU would be wise, in light of their attack, and indeed numerous such variants have been developed (e.g. [here](https://drum.lib.umd.edu/bitstream/handle/1903/7344/umi-umd-4753.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y), [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/0902.1891), and [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10623-017-0451-4)). Moreover, the authors of such papers often claim that the non-commutativity of their constructions prevents Coppersmith's attack. But where in the original paper does the argument rely on commutativity? I have been unable to pinpoint the step in their argument which requires it.

Comment: You a right to be skeptical about those non-commutative variants: they do not prevent lattice attacks.